# REGEXMATCH across multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets

My team is entering values (Discovery|Demo|Proposal|Contracting) into a set of cells (F2, I2, L2, O2, R2) to reflect sales progress. If there is no progress, they are leaving those cells blank. I would like to display in cell C2 whether any of the previously specified cells have the specified values entered into them. I can correctly populate C2 when I query against a specific cell using the formula below, but am getting errors when I try to either manually specify the additional cells ) or use an array (F2:R2).

=IF(REGEXMATCH(F2,"Discovery|Demo|Proposal|Contracting"),"yes","No")

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ArrayFormula()` in case of array input. Try-

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(REGEXMATCH(F2:L2,"Discovery|Demo|Proposal|Contracting"),"yes","No"))
```

Or `INDEX()` function will give you same result.

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(F2:L2,"Discovery|Demo|Proposal|Contracting"),"yes","No"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the function, but this is populating yes/no in all the fields in that array. I want to just populate the values in the cell the function is being entered in (C2). I want to query the array and populate in essence a summary cell.

Comment: @Chris So, any of cell is true then you want `C2` to show true? Can you just put a comment your desired output to `C2` cell my screenshot.

Comment: You may try `=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(F2:L2,"Discovery|Demo|Proposal|Contracting"),"yes","No")))` in `C2` cell.